PolynomialQ behaviour
I am crafting some functions on polynomials that must be in x. But I checked that it is always True whatever variable I use:
PolynomialQ[x^3-x+2,x]
True
PolynomialQ[x^3-x+2,y]
True
PolynomialQ[x^3-x+2,z]
True

Why?

Because you usually want something like PolynomialQ[a x^2 + b x + c, x] to be true, and the logical consequence of that is that your expression are polynomials in y/z of degree zero. PolynomialQ[_, y] basically checks that the expression doesn't involve weird functions of y such as Log[y] or y^(1/3).

We can use PolynomialExpressionQ, which has an optional 3rd argument that tests if all coefficients satisfy a constraint:
PolynomialExpressionQ[x^3 - x + 2, x, NumericQ]


True


PolynomialExpressionQ[x^3 - x + 2, y, NumericQ]


False


PolynomialExpressionQ[x^3 - x + 2, z, NumericQ]


False



Though this is not a fool proof answer:
PolynomialExpressionQ[x^3 - x + 2 + y^2 + 2y + 1 - (y + 1)^2, x, NumericQ]


False


Simplify[x^3 - x + 2 == x^3 - x + 2 + y^2 + 2y + 1 - (y + 1)^2]


True



Side note, why do both PolynomialQ and PolynomialExpressionQ exist? Only reason I found was a fringe example in the docs. Also, it would be nice if PolynomialQ also had this 3rd optional argument.


A slight variation of Julien Kluge's answer using Variables, which gives a list of all independent variables in a polynomial.
ExclusivePolynomialQ[func_, var_Symbol | var_List] := 
 With[{other = Complement[Variables[func], Flatten[{var}]]}, 
  PolynomialQ[func, var] && (other === {} || ! PolynomialQ[func, other])]

ExclusivePolynomialQ[x^3 - x + 2, x]
(* True *)
ExclusivePolynomialQ[x^3 - x + 2, y]
(* False *)
ExclusivePolynomialQ[x^3 - x + 2, z]
(* False *)
ExclusivePolynomialQ[x^3 - x + 2 + z, {x, y}]
(* False *)
ExclusivePolynomialQ[Sin[x], x]
(* False *)


The function $x^3-x+2$ is a polynomial in $x$ with coefficients {2,0,-1,1}.
For $y$ and $z$ its a polynomial with coefficients {2-x+x^3}. (See CoefficentList)
So the function is just the constant term for polynomials in $y$ or $z$.
If you need to exclude other variables, you can use a workaround:
ExclusivePolynomialQ[func_, var_Symbol | var_List] := 
 ContainsOnly[
   Select[DeleteDuplicates[Cases[func, _Symbol, {0, Infinity}]], 
    Context[#] != "System`" &], 
   If[Head[var] === Symbol, {var}, var]] && PolynomialQ[func, var]

So we can write:
ExclusivePolynomialQ[x^3 - x + 2, x]
ExclusivePolynomialQ[x^3 - x + 2, y]
ExclusivePolynomialQ[x^3 - x + 2, z]

Which yields

True
False
False



Why not something simple like NumericQ? As in ExclusivePolynomialQ[func_, var_Symbol | var_List] := AllTrue[Flatten[CoefficientList[func, var]], NumericQ]?

That... would be way easier indeed. You should answer that .

Damn! I forgot the algebra basis. You're right. But this may be a simpler solution: f[p : _?(PolynomialQ[#, x] &&
Length@# == Length@DeleteCases[CoefficientList[#, x], 0] &)]

You can use FreeQ[] to test dependence. I hope that the following function will help you:
myPolynomialQ[poly_,var_] := (Not[FreeQ[poly, var]] && PolynomialQ[poly, var]);

{myPolynomialQ[x^3 - x + 2, x], myPolynomialQ[x^3 - x + 2, y], 
 myPolynomialQ[x^3 - x + 2, z]}

(* {True, False, False} *) 

